# Array elements to appear in a different order in dropdown PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of transcribers that gets displayed in a dropdown on a page.  If the transcriber in the dropdown already has a connected assignment, their name should be moved to the bottom of the dropdown (right now it appears at the top).
I tried looping through the array, finding if there is a connected assignment and then unsetting that element and then adding it back to the end of the array, but the dropdown is still appearing in the same order.
This is my code so far:

```
echo '<datalist id="transcribers">';
    foreach ($transcribersbyworkertype[WorkerType::TRANSCRIBER] as $transcriberid => $transcriber) {
       if (!empty($this->MAssignment->findConnectedAssignment($job['id'], $transcriberid))) {  // connected assignment for transcriber
            unset($transcribersbyworkertype[WorkerType::TRANSCRIBER][$transcriberid]);
            $transcribersbyworkertype[WorkerType::TRANSCRIBER][$transcriberid] = $transcriber;
       }
    }
    foreach ($transcribersbyworkertype[WorkerType::TRANSCRIBER] as $transcriberid => $transcriber) {
        echo '<option value="' . $transcriber . '" data-id="' . $transcriberid . '" />';
    }
echo '</datalist>';
```

The key is the transcriber id, so I'm thinking that that's the problem.  Is there a way around this?

A sample of the array would be:

```
[123] = John Smith
[235] = Doris Day
```

When I find that John Smith has a connected assignment and removed him from the array and add him to the end, after Doris Day, the dropdown still shows him as the first name.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what the array looks like?

Comment: @El_Vanja, I added it to the original question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on a [simplified example](https://3v4l.org/hoESB).

Comment: @El_Vanja Maybe it makes a difference that it's put into a dropdown?  I also get the correct answer from your simplified example, but on the page, it doesn't work.

Comment: Dropdown should not affect it. Dropdowns options are shown in the order they were created in. You need to debug your code further.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into it further.